# Pyenv seems to be using outdated shims: is it safe to wipe them completely?

Tags: python, macos, homebrew, pyenv

Env: Mac OS Mojave 10.14.6

Pyenv Version: `1.2.26` (installed via homebrew)

Pyenv Python default (Pyenv global, output of `pyenv version`): `3.9.2`

With the above settings, when I try to run `python`, I get the following error:

```
<my-home-dir>/pyenv/shims/python: line 8: /usr/local/Cellar/pyenv/1.2.24.1/libexec/pyenv: No such file or directory
```

No Python versions other than global are set with Pyenv.

Somehow my shims are outdated and pointing to a non-existant Pyenv version. Is there a "best-practice" way to update the shims? Is it safe to wipe the shims directory and if so how can I recreate them? I've tried `brew upgrade pyenv` which didn't help.

Thought I would ask here before I potentially break things further. Thanks in advance for any help

Answer (score 2):

Still not sure how this happened in the first place, but restarting my shell fixed the problem. Leaving in case anyone else runs into this issue.